# how to do the class diagram for the following issue

Tags: uml

i'm working on an ads form, if i change the product's category select button, the form changes accordingly.(In fact every product has it's own properties).
did anyone know how my class diagram must look like ?

[first add product form image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gXCl.png)

[second add product form image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2bGL.png)

This is what I did so far:

[image]

Comment: Please put in some effort and do not just ask: please do my work.

Comment: Both "add product form" images look the same to me. What is the difference?

Comment: whene you change the category select value, the form bellow changes

Comment: Sorry, I put the same image twice by inadvertentity.

Comment: So, what is you issue then? Without context nobody could tell anything meaningful.

Comment: As for me, the question is quite understandable. The diagram is not good, really, but that is why he is asking. +1

Comment: You should add here a small dictionary - what is every class, distinguishing information on something from its visible representation. BTW, it is better to start from that.

Answer (score 0):

If by Picture you mean the showed form, then:

- you should add there in Picture a pair of functions, such as showFormForItemSubcategory.
- create the form classes based on an abstract formForSubcaterory class and make a reference from formForSubcaterory  to  Subcategory.

(I don't know, is your form based on subcategory or on item class. )

You could improve the variability, creating some part of Form for category, some for Subcategory and some for ItemClass.

Also, do not base items on ad. It is obviously an error. Make abstract item instead and base items on it. And it will have reference to subcategory. And Ad will have reference to AbstractItem.

Really, you are trying to do a very hard piece of work, for UI cannot be shown in class diagram in some standard way. UI diagram should be both behavioral and structure - that's the problem. And UI diagram, AFAIK, is not proposed by UML till now. (EA has something of its own, and some other tools, surely, too, but they are far from being so strict and beautifull as the class diagram). So, I would strongly advice to divide the class diagram for objects the SW is thinking about and some diagram for UI. You can make the first one strict and understandable for everybody. As for the second, you can try for something, but anyway, you will need to add many explanations to it.